# What would be the simplest token authentication DB structure?

Tags: mongodb, session, authentication, database

How would the most simple token authentication BD (in mongodb, if it matters) will look like? What field will it contain and what related info does it require.

From what I understand all I need is something like `{[token:username, token:username]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the simplest model to store the token / username match than yes, seems like the model you've described will do although you should note the following:

- Best practice is to keep token/users in some sort of in-memory
  solution ([redis](http://redis.io) for example) for better performance as you know for
  sure this info is going to be accessed almost on any call to the
  server. This of course depends on the expected load and complexity of the solution.
- Adding functionality to the mechanism will probably mean more
  fields like timestamps in order to expire the token after a certain
  amount of time
- There are some ready-to-use libraries that handle all    of that for
  you both in client and server side, depending on the    language of
  choice (node, .NET, angular, etc...) so you should probably consider using them instead of re-inventing the wheel